# Consume custom service application

Tags: wcf, service-application

I followed [this tutorial](http://sharepointegg.blogspot.sg/2009/11/create-custom-service-application-in.html) and successfully created a custom service application in my sharepoint server, my question is how to consume it from another sharepoint solution, for example I create a new empty sharepoint project and add a new application page, how I can get access to strongly type service application object from the code behind of the application page?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it the normal way by adding service reference to your service inside the project. And consume it normally as you do with any wcf service. But you need to get the config right. You should enable impersonation in the client config.